# How did Light know that Hideki Ryuga is the real L?

Tags: death-note

While watching the Death Note anime, I noticed that there was one incident when Hideki Ryuga told Light that he is the real L. Well, at that time Light was not sure if he was the real L because he thought that it might be a trap from the real L to catch him.

So my question is: how he was able to deduce that Hideki Ryuga is the real L and not a fake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

His father confirmed it.

L when tells Light his real identity, he made it in such a way that Light couldn't kill him.

1. If Light tries to kill "Hideki Ryuga", he is not sure if he is the real L. If the fake imposter dies (Like the one on TV), Light confirms he is Kira
2. He might kill the real "Hideki Ryuga" by mistake and not gain anything while exposing himself.

But he plays L's game and finally ends up in the HQ of L's team where his father confirms he is the real L. Later when L realizes about the Shinigami eyes, he tells Light that he has made arrangements with his Father that if he dies in the next few days that Light is Kira.

Thus he didn't get a chance to kill L until he was able to manipulate Rem.

EDIT: Found the source. Light's father confirms this in hospital in Manga Chapter 22. Here is the screenshot.
[image]